# Flask / Werkzeug showing up instead of error message for user connection to db

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to get the "error_statement_wrong" variable to show up when a user is trying to connect to the db with invalid credentials, but instead I get the Werkzeug showing up and stating:

"mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxx'@'DESKTOP-xxxxx' (using password: YES)"

So i know the code is most probably OK but I cannot check if the error statement does appear as it should in the web front. How do I check this?

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["POST","GET"])
def login():
        if request.method == 'POST':

            user_name = request.form.get('user_name')
            pass_word = request.form.get('pass_word')

            mydb = mysql.connect(
                  host="127.0.0.1",              
                  user=user_name,
                  password=pass_word,
                  database = "test_db"
                )

            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            sql = "select username, password from user where username=%s and password=%s"
            val = (user_name, pass_word)
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
            result = mycursor.fetchone()
            if result:
                success_statement = "Successfully logged in"
                return render_template("index0.html", success_statement=success_statement)
            else:
                error_statement_wrong = "Wrong credentials"
                return render_template("login.html", error_statement_wrong=error_statement_wrong, user_name=user_name, pass_word=pass_word)

        else:
            return render_template("login.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `mysql.connect` is throwing an error (if you weren't using `app.run` then that would result in an ugly 500 error from the wrapping web server).

The fix is to [`try`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to connect to the DB and handle the exception correctly:

```py
try:
    mydb = mysql.connect(
        host="127.0.0.1",              
        user=user_name,
        password=pass_word,
        database = "test_db"
    )
    # ... snip ...
    if not result:
        raise InvalidUserException("Username or password is invalid")
except (InvalidUserException, ProgrammingError):
    return return render_template("login.html", error_statement_wrong="Wrong credentials", user_name=user_name, pass_word=pass_word)
```

That said, are your users really connecting to the DB with the same credentials that you are storing *in* the DB for your web app?  And are you storing passwords in plain text?  (If so, you should learn more about hashing and make sure that you're using a good one-way hash for passwords)

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the trick yes! 
In regards to the hashing, we will be storing the app internally on a local server.